# OnClick event that adds text to a div, removes it if it exists, and groups by description name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar that's filled with events that's populated from a mysql database. I'm using the eventClick function of FullCalendar to send the contents of the event to a separate div so I'll be able to print out the events that I've clicked.

Using this code below, I'm able to click on the event and it adds the lines that I need to the div, but it'll add duplicates because there's nothing stopping it from doing so as I'm just appending each event when I click on one.

```
// FullCalendar eventClick function
eventClick:function(event){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        document.getElementById("event_info").innerHTML += event.description + "<br>" + event.start + "<br>" + event.end;
    });
}

// div where the information will print
<div class="col-sm-3" id="event_info"></div>
```

So I want to be able to click on a calendar event & send it to the div, but also check to see if the event has already been added and if it has, remove it. Finally, I'm looking to group the events by the description name when clicked.

I'm not sure where to start with adding those so any help or direction would be much appreciated. Thanks for your time and feel free to yell at me if I didn't explain something very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply include something like a class or data-attribute once you first add the event to the div, and then check if that is present, before adding another event?

```
var target = document.getElementById("event_info");
var isAlreadySet = target.getAttribute('data-eventAlreadySet');
var newHTML = event.description + "<br>" + event.start + "<br>" + event.end";

if (!isAlreadySet) {
    target.innerHTML += newHTML;
    target.setAttribute('data-eventAlreadySet', "true");
} else {
    // your code here if the event is already set

    // to replace the former event, use something like : 
    target.innerHTML = newHTML; // replaces the HTML
    //instead of :
    target.innerHTML += newHTML; // adds to the existing HTML
};
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to check the div innerHtml before appending a new text. Please try the following code:

```
// FullCalendar eventClick function
eventClick:function(event){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if($("div#event_info:contains("+event.description+")").length <=0)
        {
            document.getElementById("event_info").innerHTML += event.description + "<br>" + event.start + "<br>" + event.end";
        }
    });
}
```